# Remove default background from ggplot, scale axes correctly, and plot integer values as discrete

Tags: r, ggplot2

The code below produces a choropleth graph along with some points plotted, with the subregions shaded by a random designation just for this example.

I like this approach reasonably well, but would like to improve a few aspects:

1. the grey and white grid background I would like to get ride of
2. I think the state image is scaled to the size of my plot window, would prefer a more realistic relative scale for the state
3. The color scale is presented as a spectrum even though there are just a few (4 here) categories, is there a nice way to make the color legend present as a few discrete options

Currrent Code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggmap)
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
library(ggthemes)


map_data(
  "county"
) -> usa  
usa %>%
  filter(
    region == "california"
  ) -> ca

#  create some arbitrary designations for choropleth and join to main dataframe
ca_subregion_designations <- data.frame(unique(ca$subregion),sample.int(4,length(unique(ca$subregion)),replace = TRUE))
names(ca_subregion_designations) <- c("subregion","Designation")
ca <- merge(x = ca,y = ca_subregion_designations, by = "subregion")

#  Some random points in CA with some additional point status flag
ca_points <- data.frame(point_id = c(101,102,103), lat = c(37.747116,38.25502,37.961901), long = c(-122.420889,-122.631641,-121.300782), status = c('happy','sad','happy'))


# CA graph with subregions (counties) shaded by Designation and points identified by status
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(
    data = ca, 
    aes(
      x = long, 
      y = lat,
      group = group,
      fill = Designation,
    ), 
    color = "white"
  )+ 
  geom_point(
    data = ca_points, 
    aes(
      x = long, 
      y = lat,
      color =  status, 
      group=status
    ) , 
    size = 1.5, 
  )+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("happy" = "green","sad"="red"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing your desired output in turn:

1. These are controlled by `panel.background` and `panel.grid` inside `gglot2::theme`. Set them to `element_blank()`
2. Use `coord_fixed()` to make the values in each axis relative to each other
3. Because your `fill` values are integers, `ggplot2` defaults to treating them like a continuous variable. To override this, declare your fill values as `factor()` and use `scale_fill_manual()` to set the colours. I have used hex values but you can use R colour names as well.

I have exaggerated some of your values for illustrative purposes. As an aside, I recommend exploring the `sf` package if you are working with spatial data, a bit of a learning curve but it makes plotting maps a lot easier.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = ca,
               aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = factor(Designation)),
               color = "white") + 
  geom_point(data = ca_points,
             aes(x = long, y = lat, color = status, group = status),
             size = 4) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#CC79A7"),
                    name = "Designation") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("happy" = "black", "sad" = "grey40"),
                     name = "Status") +
  coord_fixed() +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = grid::unit(c(0,0,0,0), "mm"))
```

[image: result]